# Spread operator not work when I use tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

how are you? I hope well!

I'm having a rather weird problem here in Tailwindcss, when I close the scope of a component and get props like `...rest` the `className` doesn't work like it should, example:

```
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
  title: string;
  backgroundLowOpacity?: boolean;
};

export function Button({ title, backgroundLowOpacity, ...rest }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      {...rest}
      type="button"
      className={`${backgroundLowOpacity && 'bg-gray-100'}`}
    >
      {title}
    </button>
  );
}
```

That's the component, now I want to use `className` when I call it for the parent component.

```
<Button title="Sign up" className="bg-purple-500" />
```

But that doesn't work, in this case my button doesn't get the color `purple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so you are basically setting a new `className` prop in line 13, thereby overwriting the `className` prop from the `...rest` spread. This is how it's supposed to be instead:

```
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
  title: string;
  backgroundLowOpacity?: boolean;
};

export function Button({ title, backgroundLowOpacity, className, ...rest }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      {...rest}
      type="button"
      className={`${className} ${backgroundLowOpacity && 'bg-gray-100'}`}
    >
      {title}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Now this way, whatever `className` prop you pass in your component will first get added, then your short-circuit will be evaluated if `backgroundLowOpacity` is passed in as well.

Comment: You're welcome @AndresdoSantos. You should mark my answer as accepted :)